# Next Auth.js - I can't get token with getToken({req})

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I can't get the token with getToken:

[image]

This variables are ok:
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=secret
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

Here is my [...nextauth].js - I can do console.log(token) and it works well

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

...
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    encryption: true,
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return Promise.resolve(url);
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

API section (I think getToken doesnt work well):

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;

export default async (req, res) => {
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret, encryption: true });
  console.log(token);
  if (token) {
    // Signed in
    console.log("JSON Web Token", JSON.stringify(token, null, 2));
  } else {
    // Not Signed in
    res.status(401);
  }
  res.end();
};
```

Comment: The error seems to occur on the `/pages/dashboard` page. Are you also calling `getToken` there? Can you share the code from that page?

Comment: @ferhat-pektas did you solve it? if yes, how?

Comment: @Jan check the answer i posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633273/13749032

Comment: the prop `encryption: true` is no longuer available you could use `raw: true` then parse the resulat `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 7):

This might be a bug in the function but the only way i got it to work was to use getToken to get the raw jwt token and then use jsonwebtoken package to verify and decode it

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
```

```
const secret = process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET;
  const token = await getToken({
    req: req,
    secret: secret,
    raw: true,
  });
const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET);
console.log(payload);
```

Comment: where is the `userdata` variable coming from?

Comment: Sorry that shouldnt be there in the answer, ill remove it

Comment: Adding `raw: true` worked for me. Otherwise it just returns null.

Answer (score 1):

This issue still exists, but unlike other answers, I simply had to pass the `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` that I had set on my `.env` file to my `getToken()` function without setting `raw: true`.

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;

export default async (req, res) => {
  const token = await getToken({ req: req, secret: secret });
  if (token) {
    // Signed in
    console.log("JSON Web Token", JSON.stringify(token, null, 2));
  } else {
    // Not Signed in
    res.status(401);
  }
  res.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
  const secret = process.env.SECRET
  const token = await getToken({ req:req ,secret:secret});
```

also check `[...nextauth].js`, if you're using

```
adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
```

then you dont have JWT token, you have to set

```
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
```

notice this will save the session locally and not on the database

more info here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#session

Answer (score 0):

I found that a different cookie name was used for "production" and "development". Setting the correct cookie name fixed the problem.

- Development: `next-auth.session-token`
- Production: `__Secure-next-auth.session-token`

```js
const token = await getToken({
   req,
   cookieName: process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "development"
                ? "next-auth.session-token"
                : "__Secure-next-auth.session-token",
   secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
})
```

Note: `getToken` should handle this automatically, but I found that it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of using this function anymore. Since Next Auth 5 can retrieve the user from the session cookie itself.
I just imported auth from NextAuth and called const `session = await auth();` and there is my user object. But this only works on the server side.

Cons: At the time of writing Next-Auth5 is still in beta and has a dependency mismatch if you are using a Prisma adapter for next-auth.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is working:

```js
const token = await getToken({
    req: request
});
```

All you need is to write environment variables properly.

**For local:**
`NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/ NEXTAUTH_SECRET='mysecret'`

**For production:**
`NEXTAUTH_URL=https://yoururl/ NEXTAUTH_SECRET='mysecret'`

It's recommended to store production environment variables in Vercel itself.
Go to Project Dashboard > Settings > Environment Variables > Add New.